# Including a toolbar using AndroidX makes my app crashing

Tags: java, android, toolbar

Hello I looked for earlier questions about toolbars using AndroidX but didn't find an answer for my specific state, It keeps crashing while including this toolbar on my activity_main.xml :
Here's my toolbar xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" >
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

</LinearLayout>
```

My MainActivity.java code :

```
package com.hfad.bitsandpizzas.ui.activities;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import com.hfad.bitsandpizzas.R;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
}
```

And this is the dependencies that I added on my gradle build :

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

and this is my Logcat error :

***Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
at com.hfad.bitsandpizzas.ui.activities.MainActivity.onCreate***

Comment: Can you post the crash log?

Comment: I think I found the issue , Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar

Comment: where is the id of toolbar?

Comment: because the book that Iam reading he used , android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar (and since it's obsolete) I tried to migrate my code to Androidx , I'll try to fix it . Thank you

Comment: Majid , The id is mentioned on my activity_main.xml while including this toolbar

Comment: any solutions or suggestion to solve the issue?

Comment: Replace the LinearLayout with an `com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout`, and your toolbar should be `android:id="@+id/toolbar` (or any name, but must match what you `findViewById(...)`. Your Toolbar should likely be `com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar`.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini and while casting my toolbar to MaterialToolbar (or if you know any types that I can declare my toolbar to)  it shows me casting error **com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout cannot be cast to com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolba**

Comment: You're inflating the wrong View. It says: "type X cannot be cast to type Y". Meaning you wanted to `findViewById` the toolbar, but instead, found an "AppBarLayout". What is your app's theme? You're going to need to post more code here to see what you're up to, this is a very simple problem, so if you're getting strange errors, then we're not really seeing the full picture of your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you're inflating the wrong view or your theme already has a Toolbar.

#### Using the default Theme

If you use the Material Design Themes that contain an action bar (example: `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar`), then you don't need to provide an ActionBar/Toolbar for it will be there.

#### Using the Default Theme but without its "toolbar"

If you want to have your own `AppBarLayout/MaterialToolbar` (so you can customize it), then you need to change the theme for the Activity (or the whole app if you do this everywhere) to `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar`

So in either case, in your `themes.xml` where you define the App Theme...

```
<style name="Theme.MyApplication" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
  <item name="colorPrimary">@color/...</item>

Etc..
...
```

Make sure your `AndroidManifest.xml` is pointing to the theme you defined:

```
<application
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication"
    ...
```

*OR* at least define your Activity to use said theme in the Manifest:

```
        <activity
            android:name="com.your.WhateverActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication" />
```

#### What about the kotlin/java code in the Activity itself?

Depending on your solution (using the theme or providing your own) you  will need more or less code.

If you chose to use `DarkActionBar` (or light!), then you don't need anything else. Your "ActionBar" is set up for you. You don't need anything in XML either. Just `setContentView(R.layout.yourLayout)` and you're good to go.

If you elected to use the `NoActionBar` variant(s), then you won't have an ActionBar unless you add one.

So in your XML... you will need something like (note: this is the default layout that comes with the Android template for "Empty Activity", I removed the TextView and added the AppBarLAyout + Material Toolbar):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Now in MainActivity.kt...

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val toolbar = findViewById<MaterialToolbar>(R.id.toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    }
}
```

This will work if the Theme is `NoActionBar`, otherwise the `setSupportActionBar` will throw an IllegalStateException saying "you already have an action bar" or similar. There's a workaround (you can set "windowActionBar" to false in the theme to override the default but I'd rather use another theme if that's the case).

[image: Screenshot]

#### UPDATE (Java)

Java is really not much different. If your Activity were in Java, it would look like so:

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I totally understand all of this , I appreciate your help sir . Since I'm using Java code for my mainActivity can you provide me the toolbar type (bcs we all know in kotlin they provide you the right type ).